# NSURLConnection consuming huge memory

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, nsurlconnection

I'm using `NSURLConnection` to interact with the server side and I have observed that when the server take time to respond the system allows about 40 mo.
I don't know if I'm the only one to have this problem.
thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using NSURLSession?

Comment: i have a better approach using NSURLSession

Comment: yes but i still have the same problem and it's not a question of data size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible in case if your data for response is large in size. Generally what we do, we create instance of `NSData` and append all downloaded data to this variable.This works perfect when your data is comparatively small. If you have large data in response, the better way is to create file in Document directory and append all data to that file when connection receives data. Read this data after connection finishes loading.

This concept of saving data is applicable on android also.